# Why does Feitan torture when Pakunoda can search someone's memory?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In the Phantom Troupe, they have Feitan, who's the torturer to get answers out of people. But they also have Pakunoda, who can get memories out of people by just touching them.

For example in the York New arc, Feitan tortures someone to get information on where the treasure and stuff were. But why couldn't Pakunoda just get that information out by searching through his memories? It would be a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think that is Feitan's sole or primary purpose?

First, what's wrong with having 2 members of the Troupe excel at extracting information from its enemies? What if one of them is indisposed, but they need to get information out of someone?

Second, he is one of the founding members of the Troupe. While this isn't a huge deal, I doubt anyone would say to him, "hey, by the way, we don't need you anymore. We got Pakunoda now. Goodbye."

Third, Feitan is incredibly strong. He is the 5th strongest member in Phantom Troupe, in terms of sheer strength. He is easily one of the fastest.

Comment: I never said that Feitan was useless, he's actually my favorite characters. I was wondering why Pakunoda didn't interrogate the person first, which would be much easier. If she wasn't there, then Feitan would work perfectly. I think I phrased it wrong when I said that it would be a waste of time for Feitan, sorry.